# jQuery add css to current li js

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following code. When click on add-remove-image Im changing font-awesome icon, but also I want to change style of heart div. How to do this, because now style of heart div is changing only for the first li.

```
<ul id="gallery">
<li>
<div id="heart" style="display: none;"></div>
some text
<i class="add-remove-image fas fa-check"></i>
</li>
..
</ul>
```

.

```
$('.add-remove-image').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('image-added')) {
        imgArr.push($(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src'));

        $(this).addClass('image-added');
        $(this).removeClass('fa-check');
        $(this).addClass('fa-times');
        $('#heart').css("display", "block");        
    }
    else {
        var index = imgArr.indexOf($(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src'));
        if (index > -1) {
            imgArr.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $('#heart').css("display", "none");
        $(this).removeClass('fa-times');
        $(this).addClass('fa-check');
        $(this).removeClass('image-added');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have multiple "li" item with the exact same html structure, including id="heart", then its a wrong way. You have value of id attribute unique. You can try changing the id="heart" to class="heart".

Comment: My bad, but its not working. Now is setting style to all li's, not for the current.

Comment: Well, if you want to change style of the div only in the current li then should try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Instead of

```
$('#heart').css("display", "block");
```

Use this

```
$(this).parent().find('#heart').css("display", "block");
```

Simillary in the "else: statement, instead of

```
$('#heart').css("display", "none");
```

Use this

```
$(this).parent().find('#heart').css("display", "none");
```

Hope this will work for you as you expect.

Comment: I used parent() twice: $(this).parent().parent().find('.heart).css("display", "block"); 
 Thank you!